# String placeholder replaced with Object

Tags: android, string, kotlin, format

Im trying to use placeholder strings in my Android Kotlin project. According to the doc i have to use `%1$s` for a singular placeholder in string resources.

I'm using following method to print messages to the user

```
fun informUser(@StringRes stringID: Int, vararg params: String) {
    val message = main.getString(stringID, params)
    println("INFORM USER: $message")
    Snackbar.make(rootCoordinatorLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

For the purpose of this example i am using the following string resource:

```
<string name="test_placeholder">This is a %1$s test</string>
```

When calling the method like this...

```
informUser(R.string.test_placeholder, "strange")
```

...the following output is generated. Which is not the expected result.

```
I/System.out: INFORM USER: This is a [Ljava.lang.String;@18af58a test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in these lines:

```
fun informUser(@StringRes stringID: Int, vararg params: String) {
    val message = main.getString(stringID, params)
    ...
}
```

The `vararg` parameter `params` is available for use inside your function as an `Array<String>`. So instead of passing all the params you're receiving along to the `getString` call one by one, you're passing them in as just a single parameter, an array of strings. What you see substituted into your string resource, `[Ljava.lang.String;@18af58a`, is the `toString` representation of that array.

To pass along `params` as individual parameters to `getString`, use the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs):

```
val message = main.getString(stringID, *params)
```